# How to open a pdf file in a new tab inside React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf file in a new tab inside a React Typescript project.

Here is what I am trying:

```
import { Pdf } from '../path/filename.pdf';

<a href={Pdf} target='_blank'>Click Here</a>
```

But I am still getting a page not found error even though the file path and name is correct

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the curly braces around the import.

`import Pdf from '../path/filename.pdf';`

The reason this works (I'm assuming) is because since there are no named exports (since it's a file), using the curly braces will not work since React is looking for a named export called "Pdf".